# implmentation of hashtable but there is a problem in coding i cant fix it

Tags: java, string, data-structures, character, hashtable

this is my code  i think error in hash function

```
   public void   add(char k, int value) {
        int temp=Hash(k); // error in k 
        int i = temp;
        do{
            if(keys[i]==0){
                keys[i]=k;
                vals[i]=value;
                currentsize++;
                return;
            }
            if (keys [i]==k){
                vals[i]=value;
                return;
            }
            i=(i+1)%maxsize;
        }
        while(i!=temp);
  }    

  private int Hash(String k){

      return k.hashCode()%maxsize;
  }
```

…..
…..

//i need char array not string 
…..
 i think error in hash function
…...

Comment: Error in hash function  because (k) is string

Comment: You cannot complain about an error without mentioning what the error is. Include the full text of your error message and indicate which line of code causes the error.

Comment: I show now where the error